# watir-webdriver error using chrome browser

Tags: watir-webdriver

I am using watir-webdriver and getting this error message when opening a chrome browser:

```
C:\chromeDriver>irb
DL is deprecated, please use Fiddle

irb(main):001:0> require "watir-webdriver"
=> true

irb(main):002:0> a = Watir::Browser.new (:chrome)

Started ChromeDriver

port=9515

version=0.8

log=C:\chromeDriver\chromedriver.log

Selenium::WebDriver::Error::UnknownError: unknown error: unrecognized chrome option:
detach

  (Driver info: chromedriver=0.8,platform=Windows NT 6.2 x86_64)

  from C:/Ruby200/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/selenium-webdriver-2.33.0/lib/selenium/webdriver/remote/response.rb:51:in `assert_ok'                     
  from C:/Ruby200/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/selenium-webdriver-2.33.0/lib/selenium/webdriver/remote/response.rb:15:in `initialize'        
  from C:/Ruby200/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/selenium-webdriver-2.33.0/lib/selenium/webdriver/remote/http/common.rb:59:in `new'            
  from C:/Ruby200/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/selenium-webdriver-2.33.0/lib/selenium/webdriver/remote/http/common.rb:59:in `create_response'
  from C:/Ruby200/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/selenium-webdriver-2.33.0/lib/selenium/webdriver/remote/http/default.rb:66:in `request'       
  from C:/Ruby200/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/selenium-webdriver-2.33.0/lib/selenium/webdriver/remote/http/common.rb:40:in `call'           
  from C:/Ruby200/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/selenium-webdriver-2.33.0/lib/selenium/webdriver/remote/bridge.rb:629:in `raw_execute'        
  from C:/Ruby200/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/selenium-webdriver-2.33.0/lib/selenium/webdriver/remote/bridge.rb:98:in `create_session'      
  from C:/Ruby200/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/selenium-webdriver-2.33.0/lib/selenium/webdriver/remote/bridge.rb:68:in `initialize'          
  from C:/Ruby200/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/selenium-webdriver-2.33.0/lib/selenium/webdriver/chrome/bridge.rb:29:in `initialize'          
  from C:/Ruby200/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/selenium-webdriver-2.33.0/lib/selenium/webdriver/common/driver.rb:37:in `new'                 
  from C:/Ruby200/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/selenium-webdriver-2.33.0/lib/selenium/webdriver/common/driver.rb:37:in `for'                 
  from C:/Ruby200/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/selenium-webdriver-2.33.0/lib/selenium/webdriver.rb:67:in `for'                               
  from C:/Ruby200/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/watir-webdriver-0.6.4/lib/watir-webd river/browser.rb:46:in `initialize'                      
  from (irb):2:in `new'                                                                                                                  
  from (irb):2
```

Environment:

- Windows 8
- Ruby version = ruby 2.0.0p247 (2013-06-27) [i386-mingw32]

Answer (score 1):

Based on the exception, you are using selenium-webdriver version 2.33.0. My guess is there is an incompatibility between this version and your chromedriver.

Assuming you are using the latest chromedriver, you likely need to update to the latest selenium-webdriver, which is version 2.35.1.

Try a:

```
gem install selenium-webdriver
```

Comment: Also did that but still giving me the same message

Answer (score 1):

Download the new chrome driver
http://chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com/index.html?path=2.4/

I was having the same issue and updated the chrome driver, and the issue was resolved.  I also updated my gems.